# Автоматический Dispose(); у всех полей класса

Tags: c#

На сколько НЕкоректно использовать такую вот "ленивую" конструкцию диспоуза:

```
protected new void Dispose()
{
    var lst = GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        if (item is IDisposable)
            ((IDisposable)item).Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose();
}
```

и почему :)

Если в такой конструкции нету ничего плохого, почему такую конструкцию не используют повсеместно?

Да и почему вообще это не сделать "универсальным" диспоузом который (в теории) не нужно будет переопределять для того, что бы подчищать вручную все?

Comment: Например потому, что часть свойств может быть ссылками на `IDisposable`, которые являются свойствами больше чем одного объекта.

Comment: Ну и ещё по той простой причине, что рефлексия куууууудаааааа мееееедлееенннееееее, чем явный вызов Dispose там, где это необходимо

Comment: И да, Ваш код неверен. Я, конечно, с телефона, но память мне вроде не изменяет: `item` является `PropertyInfo`, а не искомым объектом. Нужно так: `if (item.GetValue(this) is IDisposable disposable) disposable.Dispose();` И учитывайте, что геттера может и не быть, так что код завалится

Comment: Одна из идей GC в том, что уничтожение 10-100 обьектов за один раз будет еффективнее чем 1. Поэтому... обьекты уничтожаются все. Но не все сразу. Подобная запись имеет смысл только если вам явно нужно освобождать ресурс принудительно. Но в большинстве случаев (даже в работе с СУБД) это не добавляет быстродействия и не улучшает работу программы. Да.. и не свойства, а поля. Потому что свойство может быть виртуальным, например не существовать в памяти, пока нету явного обращения к нему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указали в комментариях, [`GetProperties`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2) возвращает массив элементов типа [`PropertyInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Данный тип **не реализует** интерфейс `IDisposable`, соответственно проверка

```
if (item is IDisposable)
```

всегда ложна и ни у какого поля не вызывается `Dispose`.

Таким образом: такую конструкцию не используют – потому что она не работает так как ожидается.

Comment: а аналогичную по смыслу конструкцию? Теоретически можно реализовать.... Суть была в идее в общем и целом, код я, даже, не проверял толком.

Comment: @Andrew, в общем случае это весьма не тривиальная задача: свойства могут быть авто, а могут вообще не хранить значение и возвращать каждый раз новый объект, либо как уже указано в комментарии - возвращать объект который используется еще в нескольких объектах

Comment: окей, спасибо, я понял